# Node app using old environment variables after updating eccoysstem.config.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, ldap, pm2

I inhered a node server running multiple apps at once using pm2 and nginx. I just added a new app to the server and in the process of deployment, some of the env variables were set wrong for the production environment. I edited the eccosystem.confg.js to remove the extra variables, and ran the following commands:

```
pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --update-env 
pm2 save
```

After changing the ecosystem config, the app is still showing the old env vars as set. Is there some way to tell where the envs are being set? Is there a cache I need to clear? I did not set up this server in the first place, so my knowledge on where to look to change the envs is limited. I checked ecosystem.config.js, and the config file in the sites-avalibable folder.

Additional Info

Old ecosystem.config.js

```
        {
            name: "new-app-name",
            script: '/var/www/myNewApp.com/NEW-APP/app.js',
            watch_delay: 1000,
            exec_interpreter: "node@18.17.1",
            watch_delay: 1000,
            watch: true,
            env: {
                            "PORT"         : 4000,
                            "NODE_ENV"     : "production",
                            "PROTOCOL"     : "https",
                            "DOMAIN"       : "myDomain",
                            "EXTENSION"    : "com",
                            "PWD"          : "myPassword",
                            "USE_LONGJOHN" : false,
                            "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED" : 0,
                            "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS":  "/path/to/cert.pem"
                              }
          }
```

New ecosystem.config.js

```
        {
            name: "new-app-name",
            script: '/var/www/myNewApp.com/NEW-APP/app.js',
            watch_delay: 1000,
            exec_interpreter: "node@18.17.1",
            watch_delay: 1000,
            watch: true,
            env: {
                            "PORT"         : 4000,
                            "NODE_ENV"     : "production",
                            "PROTOCOL"     : "https",
                            "DOMAIN"       : "myDomain",
                            "EXTENSION"    : "com",
                            "PWD"          : "myPassword",
                            "USE_LONGJOHN" : false,
                            "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED" : 1,
                              }
          }
```

env vars set after resetting the reloading the eccosystem

```
node_version: 18.17.1
version: 1.0.0
unique_id: c96e0ae4-d2a7-49fd-8f41-d1eca6a5edff
ldap: {}
PM2_HOME: /home/pm2/.pm2
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS: /path/to/cert.pem
USE_LONGJOHN: false
EXTENSION: com
DOMAIN: mydomain
PROTOCOL: https
NODE_ENV: production
PORT: 4000
USER: pm2
SSH_CLIENT: 172.0.0.0 56122 22
XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
SHLVL: 1
MOTD_SHOWN: pam
HOME: /home/pm2
OLDPWD: /var/www/ldap.com/EDE-LDAP
NVM_BIN: /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin
SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
NVM_INC: /home/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/include/node
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
NVM_DIR: /home/admin/.nvm
LOGNAME: pm2
_: 7
XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
TERM: xterm-256color
XDG_SESSION_ID: 15
PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
SHELL: /bin/sh
LESSCLOSE: /usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
PWD: myPassword
SSH_CONNECTION: 172.0.0.0 56122 172.0.0.0 22
NVM_CD_FLAGS:
XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PM2_USAGE: CLI
PM2_JSON_PROCESSING: true
NODE_APP_INSTANCE: 0
vizion_running: false
km_link: false
watch_delay: 1000
namespace: default
script: /var/www/myNewApp.com/NEW-APP/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, I was able to fix it by deleting the app and then starting it again.

```
pm2 delete <appName>
pm2 start <appName>
```